# VBA: Having Trouble Selecting a Cell in All Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have this query that deletes all data in all Worksheets besides the first Row. I'd like to just activate cell "A2" as well on each of these worksheets but can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

```
Sub ClearWorkbook()
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        Current.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Current.Range("A2").Activate` - But why do you need to activate a cell on each page? Or is there something else you want to do?

Comment: You'd also be better served if you change `Current.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count)` to `Current.Rows("2:" & Current.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` assuming column A will always have all data possible **actual** data rows for each sheet.

Comment: It highlights all of the cells that were deleted in the worksheets. It is easier for me while copying and pasting the next set of data for the size to not already be defined. The "Range("A2").Activate" doesn't seem to work on all sheets, any ideas on that?

Comment: Are some sheets protected? Also, try `Current.Range("A2").Select`

Comment: Neither of these solutions seem to be working, even though the sheets aren't protected . Do you see any problem in this? There is data in all of the sheets as well.

Sub ClearWorkbook()
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        Current.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
        Current.Range("A2").Activate
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

```
Sub ClearWorkbook()

Dim Current As Worksheet

For Each Current In Worksheets
    If Current.Cells(Current.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row >= 2 Then
        Current.Rows("2:" & Current.Cells(Current.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    End If
    Current.Activate
    Current.Range("A2").Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be deleting the contents in row 1 as well for some reason. Thoughts?

Comment: This can happen if the sheet is already empty and `Current.Cells(Current.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` results in the header row. So, you can avoid that using the above `If` clause or you can increase that number by `+ 1`.